# How to access onCopy event value in React

Tags: reactjs

I want to edit copied content in onCopy event. But I checked that the parameter of onCopy event is a clipboardevent. So, is there a way that i can edit content on Clipboard through clipboardevent vairiable. Codes are like

```
<div onCopy = {(e)=>{//edit content through variable e}}>
//something here
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a single `<div>` with no child elements, you can access the copied content using:

```js
e.target.innerText
```

OR

```js
e.target.textContent
```

Such as:

```js
<div onCopy={(e) => console.log(e.target.innerText)}></div>


// You can use the value like this:

function MyComponent() {
   const [copiedValue, setCopiedValue] = useState("");
   return (
      <>
         <div>{copiedValue}</div>
         <div onCopy={(e) => setCopiedValue(e.target.innerText)}></div>
      </>   
   )
}
```

**NOTE:** There are important differences between `innerText` and `textContent` if your `<div>` has any child nodes. One big difference is:

> textContent gets the content of all elements, including `<script>` and `<style>` elements. In contrast, innerText only shows “human-readable” elements.

[Source MDN Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#differences_from_innertext)

---

### I'm not getting the value of what I selected, I'm getting the entire value of the element!

Using the above event target properties, you will only be able to access the *entire* contents of the element being copied. If you want to copy the selected text from the user, you could do something like this:

```js
function MyComponent() {

   const [copiedValue, setCopiedValue] = useState("");

   const handleOnCopy = (e) => {
      const selectedText = document.getSelection(); // <-- this is different
      setCopiedValue(selectedText);
   };

   return (
      <>
         <div>{copiedValue}</div>
         <div onCopy={(e) => handleOnCopy(e)}></div>
      </>   
   )

}
```

---

### I'm getting `undefined` when accessing `e.target.innerText` and `e.target.textContent`!

This could be because you're trying to access the value of an `<input>` element. If you're trying to access a checkbox's boolean state use `e.target.checked`. For all the other `<input>`'s, use `e.target.value`

Answer (score 0):

So, if you want to see the value that you are copying, just edit the code like this.

```
<div onCopy = onCopy={e => console.log(e.target.innerText)}>
```

the text is placed inside the "innerText" key.
For React just initialize a state using useState, where you can save the value.

```
const Test = () => {
const [data, setData] = useState(null)
return (
    <div onCopy={e => setData(e.target.innerText)}>
        Hello
    </div>
)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Element: `copy` event in MDN provides a good example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/copy_event

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).